# WB Discovery will soon be sponsoring Game Development Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that WB Discovery will be sponsoring Game Development Stack Exchange beginning November 29, 2023 and ending after six months. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

The sponsorship will be shown on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the mockup below:

[image: The Game Development home page with text and logos in the upper right arranged horizontally; the text is "sponsored by" and the logos are for Warner Brothers Discovery and Warner Brothers Games1]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it. If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

Also, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making Game Development Stack Exchange successful.

Comment: Today, I learned not only that Warner Bros. Discovery _exists_, but that they own a “Warner Bros. Games” division, which owns Monolith Productions (who I know for developing _The Matrix Online_ – though apparently Sony Online Entertainment operated the game for the majority of its run). I probably should've waited until the sponsorship started, but I _was_ curious..